# Extract list of objects created inside a function with their code

Tags: r, function

Lets say I have a function `ABC`

```
   ABC <- function(n1,n2,n3){
   A = mean(n1,n2,n3) 
   B = median(n1,n2,n3)
   C = sum(n1,n2,n3)
   Prod = n1*n2*n3
   Sqr = n1^2 + n2^2 + n3^2
   Result = ifelse(Prod == A, TRUE, FALSE)
   ifelse(A > B, A, B)
   }
```

So, now an imaginary function should give me the list of all objects created inside function `ABC` with their right hand side i.e. Output should be

```
   A = mean(n1,n2,n3) 
   B = median(n1,n2,n3)
   C = sum(n1,n2,n3)
   Prod = n1*n2*n3
   Sqr = n1^2 + n2^2 + n3^2
   Result = ifelse(Prod == A, TRUE, FALSE)
```

`deparse()` is by giving line numbers. Not sure how to go for using `grep()` too.

The functions available for arguments are `args()`, `formals()`, `formalArgs()` etc. if any clue on objects inside function.

**I want to do this extraction of objects and their right hand side for in-built functions inside R which have huge codes, so I want extract just the objects created inside a function or methods and their right hand sides**

Any help on how to go about it is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I just want the objects and their right hand side and not the result after user gives input.

Comment: It is not clear what you wanted.  If you need to return the values, the `list` is the way to go

Comment: @akrun Hi Please read the bold section. Forget the output which will come when user inputs the `n1`, `n2`, `n3` etc. So if You have the code with you which have some objects created inside, I just want that and no loops like `ifelse` which are also a part of function. But `ifelse` would come in output when it is assigned to a object like `Hey <- ifelse(x==2,T,F)`

Comment: @akrun For example if you see `lead()` function inside `dplyr`, it has four objects `xlen`, `n`, `out` and `attributes(out)` So I want those with their right hand side just the code and not the output

Comment: Perhaps, you could play around `body(ABC)`. E.g., at least in this case, `Filter(Negate(is.null), lapply(body(ABC), function(x) if(deparse(as.list(x)[[1]]) %in% c("=", "<-")) x else NULL))` seems valid.

Comment: @alexis_laz Nice one to start from somewhere. Let me check and edit accordingly. Then we can add our own requirements to the function to extract such objects. Will get back here soon.