# Searching All types of operators within a package using grep

Tags: r, regex, package, operators

Lets say for now considering `base` package. How can I search all types of operators within the function list of a package

To see the list of functions in `base` package, we can do

```
 ls("package:base")
```

So the above list would also have operators like **Arithmetic operators**, **Logical operators**, **Infix operators**, **Binary operators** etc.

So Basically how can I search the operators from the list using `grep()` or any other alternative function?

Example, for base package searching functions with `=` sign in it..

```
  grep("\\=",ls("package:base"),value=T)
  # [1] "!=" "<=" "="  "==" ">="
```

But it would be good if we get all types of operators at once.

How to get list of all types of operators present in R, so that we `grep` over that list of operators.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: How would you guess an operator you don't know about ? The idea in itself sounds really strange.

Comment: I am not guessing, I know bunch of types of operators, but How to get them together and do multiple patterns matching using grep

Comment: Hum, maybe `?Ops` to get the operators. As they're all functions anyway... If the Q is about to grep multiples patterns, I'm sure you can find it with a few search (mainly using `(pattern|pattern|pattern)`)

Comment: How about using `grep(paste(strsplit(intToUtf8(c(33:47, 58:64, 91:96)), "")[[1]], collapse="|"), ls("package:base"), value = TRUE)`

Comment: Your last 4 questions within 2 days ago. I see some coincidences ;)
[THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39446901/extract-list-of-objects-created-inside-a-function-with-their-code), [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39464205/how-to-get-the-list-of-in-built-functions-used-within-a-function-in-r) and [THIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39483717/searching-functions-using-grep-over-multiple-loaded-packages-in-r)

Comment: @m0h3n: Popping in my head all kinds of questions.

Comment: @akrun Will Try in sometime. Apologies. Will be back in sometime

Comment: @akrun The above comment it is not showing the operators but I guess all the functions.

Comment: I meant that you can select the operator based on `intToUtf8(c(33:47, 58:64, 91:96)` by changing the numbers, I don't know which all you need.  So was showing a general case

Answer (score 1):

i'm not sure there is a way to know a function is an opreator but
maybe this will be helpful:

```
grep(pattern = "^[^a-zA-Z]", x = ls("package:base"), value = T)
```

EDIT:
maybe this will be more helpfull:

```
getOps <- function() {
    objs <- mget(ls("package:base"), inherits = TRUE)
    funcs <- objs[sapply(objs, is.function)]
    prim <- funcs[sapply(funcs, is.primitive)]
    ops <- prim[grep(pattern = "^[^a-zA-Z]", x = names(prim))]
    ops
}

getOps()
```

Comment: Or use `grep(pattern = "^[[:punct:]]", x = ls("package:base"), value = TRUE)`

Comment: Wow nice start to it!! But I mean if you open `Arithmetic` operators you have a list, and same for `logical`, `assignment`, `binary`, `unary`, `Infix` etc. I have no clue how many other types of operator are there.

Comment: In the output some other functions are also coming which are not operators actually if we have reference list of all types of operators in R then that would help

Comment: This will miss `%in%` (out of others)

Comment: Yes this `getOps()` seems helpful, but how would I know if I have covered R's all operators? Actually I am looking into all types of operators in R.  I can see maximum of them in `getOps()`. Thank you.

Comment: its a little problematic because in R operators are just like other functions. i don't know any way do identify them uniqly

Comment: @cccmir Could you please tell me what this `getOps()` function is doing in one to two lines.

Comment: return all r primitive functions that dont start with a letter